# Task.WhenAll - not waiting for child tasks to finish

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have some problems regarding the TPL.
As you can see, I am creating 2 simple tasks and adding them to a list. 
Problem (expected behavior) is that tasks return immediately after hitting the "await" in `WorkMethodAsync` therefore rendering `Task.WhenAll` useless.
Is there a way to wait for child tasks to finish?
The only workaround I've found is faking `WorkMethodAsync` to be synchronous.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Tasks = new List<Task>();
    var myTask1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await WorkMethodAsync(), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
    var myTask2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await WorkMethodAsync(), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

    Tasks.Add(myTask1);
    Tasks.Add(myTask2);

    await Task.WhenAll(Tasks.ToArray());
}
private async Task WorkMethodAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin this is an event handler. It's perfectly fine using `async void` in this case (and only this case).

Comment: @i3arnon Yes, I'm aware of this. The calling method doesn't wait for the result of `Task.WhenAll` when you return void however, which is what I thought the issue might have been. I read your answer and realized the issue is that you're getting a `Task<Task>` which *is* completing instantly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead of `Task.Run`.

`StartNew` was built before async-await and so doesn't support it very well. In this case since your delegate returns a task and `StartNew` creates a task the return value is `Task<Task>>`. You can use `Unwrap` to get a task that represents the entire async operation:

```
Task<Task> myTask1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await WorkMethodAsync(), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
Task<Task> myTask2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await WorkMethodAsync(), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

Tasks.Add(myTask1.Unwrap());
Tasks.Add(myTask2.Unwrap());
```

However, there's really no reason to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` to begin with since `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` doesn't make sense for an async method (more on that on my blog: [LongRunning Is Useless For Task.Run With async-await](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/07/02/task-run-long-running/)) so you can just use `Task.Run`:

```
var myTask1 = Task.Run(() => WorkMethodAsync());
var myTask2 = Task.Run(() => WorkMethodAsync());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will surely check your blog!
I hope this will solve the problem of threads quitting prematurely for some reason?!

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens 1. No, it doesn't. 2. The task returned is already being executed. You can say that `Unwrap` blocks waiting for it to complete, but it doesn't.

Comment: Great answer. I had a similar problem but I still need `Task.Factory.StartNew` because I'm using another `TaskScheduler` here (one with limited concurrency).